# Drill Down to ColumnChart scrollbar issue in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to build a Drill Down chart using Highcharts.
I have a Pie chart.
On click of pie silce I am trying to show a Column chart.
[My jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nagoba/cberN/1/)
In Column chart,I need scroll bars.
Hence I have written

```
xAxis:{
min:4
}
```

in chart options.
Now when I click any pie slice.I didn't get any column displayed.
What should be done in order a drill down to column chart will have scrollbar ?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add type parameter in drillown, to check Take look at very simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/389/

```
setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.level, drilldown.type);
```